# Angular 500 error handling doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I have service which make post request and returns a data.

```
app.service('flagService', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.getData = function (r, c) {
    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/flag', { row: r, column: c }).then(function (data) {
        return data;
    })
}
}]);
```

And somewhere in the controller

```
flagService.getData(row, column).then(function () {
   console.log('it works')
})
```

But api can also return 500 status code. In this case I get "posssible unhandled rejection..." in the console. Now I would like to make simple `alert()` which will open when 500 error is returned. I've tried many, many solutions including second function, `.catch()`, `.error()`.

```
app.service('flagService', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.getData = function (r, c) {
    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/flag', { row: r, column: c }).then(function (data) {
        return data;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }).catch(function () {console.log('error')}).error(function() {console.log('error')})
}
}]);
```

But I still can't hadle error. Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interceptors for global error handling, responseError will be called whenever request is resolved with a rejection.

```
.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$injector', function ($q, $location, $injector) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 500) {
                console.log('http 500 response')
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```